# Can I control how a monitor renders its pixels?

Tags: display

I searched all the web but I was unable to find anything related or even remotely similar. I'm not even sure I'm able to explain what the problem is, because I don't have the jargon used to describe it.

I've got an LG Ultragear 32GN650, it's mostly ok, but it has one annoying thing: fonts and diagonal lines have weird horizontal line artifacts on the top edge of of them.

First I thought it has something to do with the OS anti-aliasing settings. But upon checking the pixels with a magnifier, it turns out each pixel is actually two rectangular pixels on the top of each other (each have an RGB subpixel layout but that's irrelevant here). As going from black to white the monitor lights up the top half of the pixel only, and when it's fully lit it starts to lit the bottom half.

So when a pixel is half lit, its lower half is dark, which causes this horizontal stripe effect when there is a quick transition from light to dark, like at the top edges of anti-aliased fonts or diagonal lines.

I also have an LG 24GQ50F-B monitor, which also has its pixel composed of two halves like that, but there the two halves are more evenly lit, so there are no visible horizontal line artifacts there.

Is this something that's controlled by the monitor's firmware so the user has no influence?
Is it even possible to update that firmware (my monitor have no USB ports)?

Is this something that can be fixed by installing drivers or software?

Comment: It's almost certainly inherent to the way that monitor works. Firmware upgrades for monitors are pretty uncommon, except for the really high end ones. It might be due to some post processing your monitor does, think sharpening or even dynamic contrast settings. You could try tweaking these settings via the on screen menu in the hopes this resolves your issue.